# Codeigniter language/english/_lang.php error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/_lang.php
There is rsw_lang.php in application/language/english
application/config

```
 $config['language']    = 'english';
```

Comment: the default locale is "en", does that work?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be CodeIgniter4.x. Please,  clarify.